# Applying a function to a large data set

Tags: r

I have a large dataset I am reading in R
I want to apply the `Unique()` function on it so I can work with it better, but when I try to do so, I get this prompted:

```
clients <- unique(clients)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 27.9 Mb
```

So I am trying to apply this function part by part by doing this:

```
clientsmd<-data.frame()
n<-7316738  #Amount of observations in the dataset
t<-0
for(i in 1:200){
  clientsm<-clients[1+(t*round((n/200))):(t+1)*round((n/200)),]
  clientsm<-unique(clientsm)
  clientsmd<-rbind(clientsm)
  t<-(t+1) }
```

But I get this:

```
 Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : subscript too large for 32-bit R
```

I have been told that I could do this easier with packages such as "ff" or "bigmemory" (or any other) but I don't know how to use them for this purpose.

I'd thank any kind of orientation whether is to tell me why my code won't work or to say me how could I take advantage of this packages.

Comment: If `clients` is your whole dataframe, I suppose it has a column with a unique identifier. Say this column is called `id`. It might be worthwhile trying to see if `unique(clients$id)` or preferably `duplicated(clients$id)` works. This also enables you to subset `clients` to get all duplicates, which you can then check further including other columns.

Comment: how much RAM do you have and what's the size of your `data.frame`? also it's important if you have 32 or 64 bit operating system. Your problem looks like simple memory issue, sometimes calling `gc()` function can help, or closing R and starting it again, you may try to free more RAM in your system by closing other running applications. And don't be scared to get familiar with `ff` and `ffbase` packages, you can convert you `data.frame` to `ffdf` like this `clients_ffdf <- as.ffdf(clients)` and then work with it practically like with usual `data.frame`

Answer (score 1):

Is **clients** a data.frame of data.table? **data.table** can handle quite large amounts of data compared to data.frame

```
library(data.table)

clients<-data.table(clients)

clientsUnique<-unique(clients)
```

or

```
duplicateIndex <-duplicated(clients)
```

will give rows that are duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

increase your memory limit like below and then try executing.

```
 memory.limit(4000)   ## windows specific command
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use distinct function from dplyr package .

function - `df %>% distinct(ID)`

where ID is  something unique in your dataframe .

Comment: What does it means `df %>%` ?

Comment: Its an operator used in dplyr package .
For more clarity open this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941080/meaning-of-symbol-in-r